# Vim positive look behind match pattern

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

Here is the code:

```js
return (

    <div></div>
)
```

Notice there is a blank line above `<div></div>`.

I want to match `<` in `<div>`. Here is what I have tried:

- Pattern `\((\_s*\)\@<=<` won't work, but `\((\_s*\)\zs<` work.
- Pattern `\((\_s*\)\@<=<` work only when I remove the blank line above `.

So, my questions are:

- What's the difference between `\@<=` and `\zs`?
- How to use `\@<=` to match the `<` without remove the blank line above? (This one is more important to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between `\@<=` and `\zs`?

1. The *lookbehind* operator `\@<=` cannot search earlier than the previous line
2. `\zs` and `\ze` allow you to explicitly define the match

See `:help \@<=` and `:help \zs`

> How to use `\@<=` to match the `<` without remove the blank line above?

You cannot. For performance reasons, lookbehind will not look 2 lines before the match